# Converting from []T1 to []T2 when T2 has the underlying type of T1

Tags: go, type-conversion

Two closely related question:

Why doesn't [Go Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) allow you to convert `[]T1` to `[]T2` if `T2` has the underlying type of `T1`?

What are the negative consequences of doing the conversion using the `unsafe` package?

**Example:**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

type T1 struct {
    Val int
}

// T2 has the underlying type of T1
type T2 T1

func main() {
    a := []T1{T1{12}}

    // cannot convert a (type []T1) to type []T2
    //b := ([]T2)(a)

    // But with some unsafe we can do it.
    // So, why doesn't Go allow it? And what unforeseen consequence might it have?
    b := *(*[]T2)(unsafe.Pointer(&a))
    b[0].Val = 42

    fmt.Println(a[0].Val) // 42
}
```

**Playground:** http://play.golang.org/p/x2tBRKuRF1

**Example of usage:**

If T1 implements a certain interface, say `json.Marshaler`, and you want to JSON encode the type in a different way, you create a new `type T2 T1` with its own implementation of `json.Marshaler`.

It works fine when marshaling single values, but when you get a []T1 slice you would have to either copy it to a []T2 slice or create a new `type ST1 []T1` with its own `MarshalJSON()` method. It would be nice to do a simple conversion instead instead of having to turn to `unsafe` as it might result in runtime errors instead of compile time.

Answer (score 1):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Conversions](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions)
>
> A non-constant value x can be converted to type T if x's type and T
>   have identical underlying types.

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type T1 struct {
    Val int
}

type T2 T1

type ST1 []T1

type ST2 ST1

func main() {
    a := ST1{T1{42}}
    fmt.Println(a) // 42
    // convert a (type ST1) to type []ST2
    b := ST2(a)
    fmt.Println(b) // 42
}
```

Output:

```
[{42}]
[{42}]
```

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I was more wondering why the specs doesn't allow it. If the memory representation are the same (which they obviously are with the same underlying type), why would they decide to prevent such conversion? I update my question.

Comment: @Greg Go specs allow you to convert from T1 to T2 if they have the same underlying type. But not from []T1 to []T2; then you will have a compiler error.

Comment: @ANisus gotcha, i misunderstood :)